# Unable to view images on reverse proxy

Tags: apache, server, reverse-proxy, httpd.conf

I have configured reverse proxy on a local virtual box and I have installed WebLogic server on following IP address 192.168.0.203 (which is on a local network).
I have entered following details on httpd.conf

```html
<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1:80>
     ServerName www.nikhilesh.com
     ServerAlias nikhilesh.com
     ErrorLog /var/log/httpd/error_log
     TransferLog /var/log/httpd/access_log

     <Location />
    ProxyPass  http://xxxxxxxx.xxxxx.com:7001/console/ retry=0
    ProxyPassReverse  http://xxxxxxx.xxxxx.com:7001/console/
    ProxyHTMLURLMap   http://xxxxxxx.xxxxxx.com:7001/console/
    RequestHeader    unset  Accept-Encoding
    #ProxyRequests off
    ProxyHTMLEnable On
    SetOutputFilter proxy-html
    ProxyHTMLDoctype XHTML
    ProxyHTMLStripComments on
    SetEnv force-proxy-request-1.0 1
    SetEnv proxy-nokeepalive 1
     </Location>

#ProxyPreserveHost On
</VirtualHost>
```

I have entered following details in the host file

```html
192.168.0.203   xxxxxxx.xxxxxx.com    xxxxxx
```

I have restarted the server
I have entered following address(www.nikhilesh.com/) on the browser it is showing 
[image]

Actually, it should display
[image]

when I am entering the credentials and click on the login button
it displays following error
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The WebLogic admin console assumes a context path of /console and that ProxyHTMLURLMap probably doesn't filter all the URLs, I bet it misses resources linked in the CSS file.

Try setting your location directive to /console (and use /console when testing with a browser). Or alternatively, try setting the "console context path" in the domain configuration in the admin console to an empty value - though I am not sure if that is allowed.

Comment: Thanks it worked.Still i am facing the little bit issue when iam clicking on server in domain configuration area it is displaying original ip address of the server in browser address bar and redirecting to Login page

Comment: That might be solveable by setting the adress of your webserver as the "front end host" and appropiate port under AdminServer -> Protocols -> HTTP and restarting the admin server. 

(Also, don't forget to mark the question as answered!)